# Issue related to view.officeapps.live.com viewer. Every time it shows or pickup previous excel file not the latest file

Tags: html

I used view.officeapps.live.com viewer for showing excel file. When I use office online view service provided by microsoft, it will show previous file not showing latest excel file. I think it shows file which is saved in cache foldar. Is any one know how to solved this issue ?

Comment: As you think it is a cache problem have you tried to find out how to refresh the cache?

Comment: The caching happens on the server. Clearing your (browser) cache doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the office side cache, You could simply resolve this issue by adding a timespan to the filename and then at resolve time on the server side, remove that timespan and continue your business logic.